# How to calculate LatLngBounds of the MapView with zoomLevel and LatLng of map center?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have found many discussions about given LatLngBounds, how to get a fit zoom level. But now I meet a problem that I know current location of map center, and I can get what current zoom level is, and I wanna know the LatLng of the north-east corner and the south-west corner of my map view.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Projection` of the map and the `VisibleRegion`:

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

Then you can get the `VisibleRegion`'s `farLeft`, `farRight`, `nearLeft` and `nearRight` coordinates. So, if you need a `LatLngBounds` you can do:

```
LatLngBounds mapBounds = new LatLngBounds(visibleRegion.farLeft, visibleRegion.nearRight);
```